# Assign scanned values from file to object's parameters?

Tags: java, file

I am scanning a file that has an athelete's name and his scores:

```
John Smith; 24; 14;
Adam West; 17; 9;
```

How can I separate these values? As in John Smith is the name, 24 is his A score, 14 is his B score? I'm thinking to create an "Athlete" object with such parameters, but I don't know how to 'assign' them.

My scan:

```
        File file = new File ("input.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
        }
```

Comment: "_I'm thinking to create an "Athlete" object with such parameters_" - start by creating the `Athlete` class, with the corresponding attributes (name, scoreA, scoreB), constructor, etc. If you got that down, take your input as you do, then `split()` each line on the semicolon (hint: `trim()` will remove unnecessary whitespaces), use `Integer.parseInt()` to parse the scores and build your `Athlete` objects with these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on how question was asked I assume that you start with Java (or programming).

**Beginner approach** would be to split each line:

```java
  String line = scan.nextLine();
  String[] fields = line.split(";");
  String name = fields[0];
  String aScore = fields[1];
  String bScore = fields[2];
```

Then you can figure out the rest. Of course this code needs error handling, because there can be less (or even no semicolons).

More on split: https://www.baeldung.com/string/split

In **comercial environment** instead of doing that on your own you'd be better off using one of available libraries that parse CSV-like files like [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/). Then you can define named headers and rely on external library to handle errors in input file for you.

Comment: Given that the input is not just separated on semicolons, it's also got spaces in it, that should either be `.split("\\s*;\\s*")` in order to split on the concept of 'any amount of whitespace, then a semicolon, then any amount of whitespace', or, the assignments to the 3 variables should invoke `.trim()`, e.g. `String name = fields[0].trim();`.